# Xamarin Forms Hide a Button on iOS and Show it on Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visibility

How to hide a button, a label or a grid cell on iOS and show it on android, I have a xamarin.forms app (portable), I know that I have to use on platform but how to access the visibility of the controls.

Thanks

Comment: <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="IsVisible"  iOS="True" Android="False" /> but the app crashes: Type IsVisible not found in xmlns that's why I need to know what do I have to put the x:TypeArguments

Comment: Hi @Mireille, check out my answer, it should help you :) If it does, tag it as an answer so it'll help other people! :)

Comment: Just for clarification: "IsVisible" is the property name. What you should assing to x:TypeArguments is the actualy type of the property, which is a bool (x:Boolean in standard content page)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
// IOS, Android, WP
SomeButton.IsVisible = Device.OnPlatform<bool>(false, true, true);
```

Or

```
if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Android)
{
    SomeButton.IsVisible = true;
}
else
...
```

Answer (score 49):

If you want to do it on XAML, in order to hide a view on a specific platform, you can use this:

```
  <Button>
      <Button.IsVisible>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Boolean"
                      iOS="false"
                      Android="true"/>
      </Button.IsVisible>
    </Button>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it helped me a lot

Comment: Glad I helped! But, it looks like you were looking for the answer through code-behind.

Answer (score 5):

From Xamarin.Forms version 2.5.x this is done as per code below. Using a basic button as an example.

```
<Button Text="NFC Pairing" Command="{Binding YourVmCommand}">
    <Button.IsVisible>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Boolean">
            <On Platform="iOS">true</On>
            <On Platform="Android">false</On>
        </OnPlatform>
    </Button.IsVisible>
</Button>
```

Nigel

Answer (score 4):

All of these answers seem to involve creating the control whether or not you actually need it and then setting IsVisible to false on the platforms you don't want it on. A better solution IMO is to only create the control in the first place if you do in fact need it. A first step would be to wrap it in a content view:

```
<ContentView>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="View">
        <OnPlatform.Android>
            <Button Text="Something" ...etc... />
        </OnPlatform.Android>
    </OnPlatform>
</ContentView>
```

That's better, but it still creates a superfluous ContentView. Take it one step further and use OnPlatform to declare a ControlTemplate and you'll achieve the most optimal implementation across all platforms.

Answer (score 4):

Expanding the solutions, you can also do xaml inline:

```
IsVisible="{OnPlatform iOS=true, Android=false}"
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Compact and very useful.

Answer (score 3):

Like mindOfAi mentioned you can do this in XAML like this:

```
<Button>
    <Button.IsVisible>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Boolean"
                      iOS="false"
                      Android="true"/>
    </Button.IsVisible>
</Button>
```

In code you can use the [Device.OnPlatform](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Device.OnPlatform/) or check the [Device.OS](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.Device.OS/) property.

That would look like:

```
// ... Other code here
Device.OnPlatform(iOS: () => { myButton.IsVisible = false; });

// Or do this:
if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS)
    myButton.IsVisible = false;

// ... Other code here
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that stumbles upon this question seeking for the codebehind solution:

```
            switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
            {
                case Device.iOS:
                    //iOS specific code here
                    break;
                case Device.Android:
                     //Android specific code here
                    break;
            }
```

The Device class has the following Device constants:

[Constants as shown from VS 2019 Intellisense](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjJAV.png).

Answer (score 0):

Lots of answers that are accurate but deprecated, the new way to to it is:

```
<Button ...>
    <Button.IsVisible>    
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Boolean">
            <On Platform="iOS" Value="False"/>
            <On Platform="Android" Value="True" />
        </OnPlatform>
    </Button.IsVisible>
</Button>
```

You can of course use other platforms as well. Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/essential-xaml-syntax